# Connect to Robomongo in a network proxy

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I had some connections on Robomongo that worked well, because network didn't have any type of restriction. Now, in the company, network is very restricted and they gave us a Network proxy and some specific IP's, but now, robomongo doesn't allow me to connect to any database, but local.

How can I configure robomongo with this parameters they gave us?

This is the message I get

> Cannot connect to the MongoDB at c100.candidate.10.mongolayer.com:10101.
>
> Error: Network is unreachable

Comment: When you can't connect with RoboMongo, what's the error message you get?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Question updated!